# Conda: Choose where packages are downloaded

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I don't have enough space in my default conda directory so I want conda packages to be downloaded at a different location. I have a conda environment created and activated at

```
/different_drive/condaenv
```

Based on what I found online, I tried editing the .condarc file to have

```
pkgs_dirs
 - /different_drive/pkgs
```

and edited the permission of the default directory

```
/home/user/conda/pkgs/
```

to read-only. However, I just get permission denied errors as conda still tries to download the files to the default directory. Any suggestions on what I can do to change the download location of the packages?

Comment: Have you got the syntax correct in your .condarc?
Run "conda config --show" from the command line and see if the anticipated directory is the first in the list.

Comment: Does not seem to be reproducible on conda 4.8.1, Python3.7 while installing PyQt.
I cleared the contents of pkgs, set the permissions to 500 on the pkgs directory and the installation of the PyQt went successfully.

Comment: could it be that you are just missing the colon (:) after `pkgs_dirs`? also verify the permissions set on the new folder, especially if you are working in a multiuser environment.

Answer (score 8):

In case other people encounter the same problem, as suggested in one of the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57416542/15453241), the following command changes `pkgs_dirs`:

```
conda config --add pkgs_dirs /new_path_pkgs/
```

You can then check the new value of `pkgs_dirs` with:

```
conda config --show
```

Answer (score 3):

The steps provided at the [official conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#specifying-a-location-for-an-environment) link, answers the question.

After creating the environment, activate it, then install your packages. The packages shall be installed within this environment and not the default location.

**Update**

Reproducing the commands below for quick reference:

Following command will create a new environment in a subdirectory of the current working directory called `demo`

```bash
conda create --prefix ./demo python=3.6 scipy=0.15.0
```

Now, activate the environment as follows:

```bash
conda activate ./demo
```

The environment prompt will have absolute path to the environment, to shorten it, use the trick mentioned at the link above.

Comment: please note that the `--n` or `--name` option is not used when the `--prefix` option is used!

Comment: This only describes how you can move the location for environments. But how do you move the location of conda/pkgs/ ? I run into the problem that my path names within that directory get too long, and conda apparently is more restrictive in those terms than Windows. So, other than uninstalling and reinstalling everything, how can you move the package cache?

Comment: If you are asking about how to move _already_ installed packages, I doubt that is easily achievable.

Answer (score 0):

You can set enviroment variables:

```
export CONDA_ENVS_PATH=/my-favorite-path-to/conda-envs
export CONDA_PKGS_DIRS=/my-favorite-path-to/conda-pkgs
```

and put this e.g. in your `.bashrc` file.

Packages will be downloaded to `CONDA_PKGS_DIRS` and environments will be created in `CONDA_ENVS_PATH`.

Answer (score -2):

I think you might be able to create a new environment with a different path and have your packages installed on that path. Or better you can change your existing conda environment to a new path where you'd have more space. Check [this link out.](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Moving just the environments won't help. The package cache will still store a copy of every package.