# Change conda default pkgs_dirs and envs dirs

Tags: linux, conda

I am using conda on a cluster. There is a space limit on the /home directory.
This has reached its limits and I would like to move the ~/.conda directory to another one keeping already installed packages. What is the best way to proceed?

conda version : 4.7.5

Linux: centos

I tried:

`conda config --set pkgs_dirs /mnt/lustre/users/bdiallo/.conda/pkgs/`

and got the following error message:

`CondaValueError: Key 'pkgs_dirs' is not a known primitive parameter.`

Comment: This is probably because `pkgs_dirs` is a multi-value parameter. You need to use `--add` or `--append`

Comment: Thank you using `--add` before did work.  Now I simply copy-pasted the content of the previous directory to the new. Will that be enough for conda to work properly with the old packages.

Comment: I don't know, sorry!

Comment: You can open `.condarc` file and modify them manually. Read more: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-env-directories

Answer (score 9):

Windows:
`conda config --add pkgs_dirs \\server\share\conda\pkgs`

Linux:
`conda config --add pkgs_dirs /mnt/lustre/users/bdiallo/.conda/pkgs/`

Or manually edit `.condarc` in your home directory ([ref](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-package-directories-pkgs-dirs)):

```
pkgs_dirs:
  - /opt/anaconda/pkgs
```

Watch for typos, both pkg and dir need to be plural: `pkgs_dirs`.

*Thanks to @darthbith and @naeem-khoshnevis in comments.*